# UPnP library for Java

Tags: java, upnp, service-discovery

Is there a library for implementing service discovery and publishing via UPnP?

(I am trying to find some alternatives to JmDNS that while protocol-wise worked fine for our purposes, was highly unstable as a library, having an unacceptably bad tendency for deadlocking itself.)

Comment: You can also try: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cgupnpjava/

Comment: I think we fixed all the deadlocks we ever found in JmDNS, but it has far bigger problems than that, e.g. it doesn't work *at all* on some systems.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

http://4thline.org/projects/cling/

Open Source DLNA/UPnP stack, libraries, and tools for Java and Android developers

Comment: @Roland : Can u just tell me what exactly u r about to do? i need help on discovering the UPnP device in android.. I want to make app which my android device serves as a medium which can be able to stream media from internet and then make available to UPnP device..Any help on this..

Comment: Thanks i was looking forward for this only...thanks

Comment: We need it for integration with a 3rd party POS system that uses UPnP for comunication and negotiation. I can't really help you out in your particular case (fwiw - I find UPnP to be an extremely ugly protocol)

Comment: I have made an app with this library (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mikebevz.upnp) but the library throws NulPointerException on Android 3.0+ devices. Does anyone see this problem?

Comment: The library is no longer maintained so probably not a good choice anymore

Answer (score 9):

You could also try [ohNet](http://wiki.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet) which includes Java bindings and control point / device stacks under a BSD license.

(Disclaimer: I have contributed to this project)

Comment: interesting... but i can not found how can i get my gateway UDN with it. is it possible to do that?

Comment: @IMAnis_tn use CpDeviceListUpnpDeviceType("upnp.org", "InternetGatewayDevice", 1, listener).  'listener' will be called back each time such a device is found.  Use the getUdn() function to retrieve the device udn.  You could also use CpDeviceListUpnpServiceType if you want to search for a particular service type.

Comment: @IMAnis_tn it'd also be worth having a look at the Control Point overview on the [project wiki](http://www.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet) for details on how to initialise the library

Comment: Looks like it is not 100% Java.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen that's correct.  Its a C++ library with Java wrappers for all public APIs.  The C++ code can be built for Android, Windows, Mac & Linux so can be trivially deployed to platforms most likely to host Java.  Ports to other OSes would be possible too.

Comment: @simonc, hmm why aren't there some getting-started samples

Comment: @Pacerier the [overview docs](http://www.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet#Overview_docs) cover this