# Example of simple port forwarding using any UPnP library in Java?

Tags: java, .net, c, upnp, nat-traversal

I want to open port 5555 on my machine using UPnP to the world. Could you please provide me with such Java sample for any sutable Opensource library. I need A CODE SAMPLE like one I can give you for C# using [this lib](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetportmapper/)

```
using TCMPortMapper;

private void Form1_Load()
{
  PortMapper.SharedInstance.Start();
  PortMapping pm = new PortMapping(localPort, publicPort, 
         PortMappingTransportProtocol.TCP);
  PortMapper.SharedInstance.AddPortMapping(pm);
}
private void Form1_FormClosing()
{
  PortMapper.SharedInstance.StopBlocking();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPnP library for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229665/upnp-library-for-java)

Comment: wonder if Jeff should make the search box blink and wave?

Comment: I need a clear and simple code sample of using Java lib, not links to tham!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried googling for "[java upnp library"](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=java+upnp+library&qscrl=1)?

My first hit was one [UPNPLib](http://www.sbbi.net/site/upnp/index.html) that looks reasonable. [sample for UPNP mapping](http://www.sbbi.net/site/upnp/docs/natmappings.html) with same.
there are also others:

- [weupnp](http://code.google.com/p/weupnp/)
- [cling](http://teleal.org/projects/cling/)